# JFileChooser and JTextField connect

Tags: java, swing, file, textfield, jfilechooser

I have a `JTextField` and a `JFileChooser`. In the file chooser I want to select a file and then display it in the text field. Unfortunately this does not work. Can one any help me?

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    jFileChooser1 = new JFileChooser();
    int value = jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (value == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File selectedFile = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: `textField.setText(selectedFile.getPath())`?

Answer (score 1):

`textField.setText(selectedFile.getPath())`?

As I'm sure, by now, you're aware, `JTextField#setText` expects a `String`, so you need to use one of the `File` methods to generate a `String` representation of the `File` object.

If you don't want the full path/name of the `File`, you could also just use `File#getName`, which returns just the name of the `File` without the path

Have a closer look at the [`File` JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) for more details